# Conservation of angular momentum affects the amplitude of the wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering-cross-section

In Griffiths Quantum mechanics book (Scattering theory-phase shifts):

> Because the angular momentum is conserved (by a spherically symmetric potential), each partial wave(labelled by a particular l) scatters independently, with again no change in amplitude.

How does the conservation of angular momentum affect the amplitude of the scattered wave?

Comment: Amplitude and angular speed gives energy transported. Now if things are conserved then change in one variable cause other to change. This is similar in angular momentum.

Comment: What Chapter/Section/Page?

Comment: Ch 10, Sec 3, P.386 @hft

Comment: I guess I have a different edition than you. What is the section name. I'm trying to locate the quote you provided. Can you provide any other context? Is this in the First Born Approximation?

Comment: It's in the phase shifts section. I guess phase shifts was included in the partial wave amplitude section and recently it becomes a section by itself.